# CNG: When to use BCrypt* vs NCrypt* family of functions

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, cng

In the Microsoft CNG API (Cryptography API: Next Generation), there are two sets of functions that appear to do the same thing.

The following functions start with `BCrypt` and perform key import/export, encryption/decryption, sign/verify, and Diffie-Hellman key exchange

```
BCryptExportKey
BCryptImportKey
BCryptEncrypt
BCryptDecrypt
BCryptSignHash
BCryptVerifySignature
BCryptSecretAgreement
BCryptDeriveKey
```

But the same set of functions exist which start with `NCrypt`:

```
NCryptExportKey
NCryptImportKey
NCryptEncrypt
NCryptDecrypt
NCryptSignHash
NCryptVerifySignature
NCryptSecretAgreement
NCryptDeriveKey
```

What's the difference between these two sets of functions, and when should each one be used?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `BCrypt` family of function are classified as **[Cryptographic Primitives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204776(v=vs.85).aspx)**, while the `NCrypt` family of functions are classified as **[Key Storage and Retrieval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx)**.

The primary difference is that the `BCrypt` functions are used when dealing only with ephemeral keys, while the `NCrypt` functions are used when persistent keys are required.

In practice, the `BCrypt` functions are typically used for hashing and symmetric encryption, while the `NCrypt` functions are used for public/private key encryption and decryption, public/private key signing and verification, and shared secret (e.g. DH and ECDH) negotiation.

While some public/private key operations can be done with `BCrypt` functions, they can only be used with ephemeral keys and are therefore of limited use.

Persistent keys are stored in key containers specific to each user (or to the system).  This is a security measure to ensure that users can't view each other's private keys.

In general, you'll want to use the following functions for the following operations:

- `BCryptHashData`: Used for hashing and HMAC (MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512)

  - Related: `BCryptCreateHash`, `BCryptFinishHash`, `BCryptDestroyHash`
- `BCryptEncrypt`: Symmetric key encryption (DES, 3DES, AES).

  - Related: `BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey`, `BCryptDestroyKey`
- `BCryptDecrypt`: Symmetric key decryption (DES, 3DES, AES).

  - Related: `BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey`, `BCryptDestroyKey`
- `NCryptEncrypt`: Asymmetric key encryption (RSA)
- `NCryptDecrypt`: Asymmetric key decryption (RSA)
- `NCryptSignHash`: Asymetric key signature (RSA, DSA, ECDSA)
- `NCryptVerifySignature`: Asymmetric key signature verification (RSA, DSA, ECDSA)
- `NCryptSecretAgreement`: Asymmetric key secret sharing (DH, ECDH)

  - Related: `NCryptDeriveKey`

Examples are available at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204779(v=vs.85).aspx) for several of these cases.

For a real world example, I've implemented all of these in the [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) source code, specifically the `encrypt_cng.c` file (there are typedefs in place, defined in `encryption.h`, to allow the functions in this file to implement a common application level API to allow the use of other crypto libraries such as CryptoAPI and OpenSSL).

Comment: With the old CSP was very limited and so no intuitive, yet it was somehow forcing for strong key storage mechanism. however with NCrypt* key storage is a bit weird ! for instance to get an ephemeral key you still need to call NCryptCreatePersistedKey .. The NCrypt is somehow trying to memic PKCS11 but really in a very strange way that is far from intuitive .. and consequently error prone

Answer (score 12):

Use `BCrypt*` functions when you have the key in the memory of your application.

Use `NCrypt*` functions when you store the key in a KSP (Key Storage Provider).

`NCrypt*` functions do a lot of extra work and are less efficient, so if you are not storing the key in the KSP it is better to use the `BCrypt*` functions.

As most long-term stored keys are asymmetric (RSA, ECDSA, ...) keys, `NCrypt*` functions are more commonly used with aymmetric algorithms. `BCrypt*` is commonly used for both asymmetric and symmetric algorithms.